# Starting an SQL Server... beginner Problem

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to get an SQL Server 2008 Express to work. I'm a real beginner and a bit bit stuck.
When i open the Configurationsmanager, there are not entries shown in the categorie for the SQLServer Services.

[Screenshot http://img3.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/screenshot58shqnalj6o.jpg](http://img3.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/screenshot58shqnalj6o.jpg)

I'm want to start the server an connect to it, via SQL Server Management Studio. On MSDN i've read so far to rightclick on the
detail window for SQL Services and then select the start option. But there are no entries and no start option showing.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?
Thx :-)

Comment: You should definitely see something there! What does the message in the window translate to?

Comment: Something like "No Elements shown in this view"

Comment: I'd check the services applet also (start->run->services.msc) if there's nothing there then run the install again.

Answer (score 0):

I installed it again and it worked fine....